# Designar directorio de docker de Informix

Tags: linux, docker, informix

Estoy intentando hacer que el docker de informix (nombre ifx) que los datos que se guarden en la base de datos, se reflejen en un directorio de linux (ej: /opt/ibm/datos).
El docker de instalación es el siguiente:
`docker run -it --name ifx -h ifx--privileged -p 9088:9088 -p 9089:9089 -p 27017:27017 -p 27018:27018 -p 27883:27883 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest`

Intenté utilizar el parametro `-v`con el direcotrio que indiqué arriba, pero se pierden los datos, no los guarda ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La Documentación esta en el [github](https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/14.10.FC1/informix-developer-database.md) de la imagen.
Para tu ejemplo corre el comando asi:

```
docker run -it --name ifx -h ifx--privileged -p 9088:9088 -p 9089:9089 -p 27017:27017 -p 27018:27018 -v /opt/ibm/datos:/opt/ibm/data -p 27883:27883 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest
```

Tienes que añadir la bandera `-v ...` para crear un volumen dentro del contenedor en `/opt/ibm/data` hacia tu directorio `/opt/ibm/datos` en el host.

Comment: Excelente! Gracias!

Comment: es que intenté hacerlo con la documentación, pero no logré que quedaran los datos